# Prevent Elasticsearch re-index on update by query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Elasticsearch 5 with Nest 5 on C#.

I have an entity like this:

```
public class Visitor {
...
    public List<ESRecipient> RecipientOf { get; set; }
...
```

A mapping like this

```
.Index(ESIndexName) 
.Settings(s => s
    ...
    .RefreshInterval("10s")
    ...
)
.Mappings(m => m
    .Map<Visitor>(map => map

        // Routing required
        .AutoMap().RoutingField(r => r.Required(true))

        // Custom Properties
        ...
        .Properties(p => p.Nested<ESRecipient>(n => n.Name(name => name.RecipientOf).AutoMap()))
        ...
```

I am doing an update by query like this:

```
client.UpdateByQuery<Visitor>(u => u
.Script(script => script
    .Inline(@"
    ...
    ")
 )
.ScrollSize(10000)
.RequestsPerSecond(-1)
.Refresh(false)
```

The problem I have is that when I run the update by query it take around 8 second to update 30000 visitors, but if I change the index RefreshInterval to 30 seconds then the update takes 100 miliseconds to run. So my guess is that Elasticsearch it is just ignoring the refresh=false query string in this case and it is just refresing the index after the update.

What I expect is to run this update in 100 ms when I set the ".Refresh(false)" in the update statement event if I just leave the index refresh interval to 1 second as it is by default.

Comment: The `refresh` parameter in the update-by-query API works differently than the one for the index API. Read more here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#_url_parameters_2

Comment: The default value for `refresh` is `false` if none is supplied

Comment: Then how can I prevent the index refresh after the update? and why it is refreshing the index if I set an refresh interval of 10 seconds but not if I set it to 30 seconds.

Comment: Not supplying a value for `refresh` is the same as supplying a value of `false`. New segments will be written whenever a refresh interval is set greater than 0; the size of the refresh interval can make a large difference to indexing throughput however. I suspect that a 1 second refresh interval in conjunction with the update query is what makes the query take 8 seconds. You might consider disabling the refresh interval whilst updating by query, then enabling after